# Jquery Loop all img tags which are only in <article><article> and not in <header></header>

Tags: jquery

I want to loop all img tags which are only in article tag and not in header tags with jquery.
Please help me.

Comment: `$('article img').each(function(){ /*your code here*/ });`

Comment: @VictorLevin Thank you very much. I've solved problem.

Comment: @VictorLevin one more question. if there is a header tag in article tag and there is img tag in header tag then what will I do?

Comment: `$('article > img')` ----- this means `img` tags that are direct children of `article` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's dipends. If you have only one article tag you can use this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('article img').each(function(){
      //get the images
   })
})
```

NOTE: this is just an example to help you out, because you don't say what you want to do with the founded images. But maybe You know how to implement this to do what you need.

Comment: That's it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
function processEachImgTag()
{
    var imgsDirectlyUnderArticle = $("article > img"); 
    var imgsNestedUnderArticle = $("article img");
    imgsDirectlyUnderArticle.each(function( index ) {
        //do stuff
    });
}
```

jQuery each(): https://api.jquery.com/each/

jQuery selectors: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp